# Partially BV vector fields and renormalization

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Why does the approach used to prove Theorem 4.1 in [the paper by Le Bris and Lions on *Renormalized solutions of some transport equations with partially $W^{1,1}$ velocities and applications*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10231-003-0082-4) **not** work for "partially $BV$" vector fields?

---

The argument of Le Bris and Lions is outlined in Section 4 of [this survey](http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=BUMI_2007_8_10B_1_25_0) on page 12-13 and goes as follows:

$$\Phi_\epsilon (t,x,y)=\left(X(t,x), \frac{X(t,x+\epsilon y)- X(t,x)}{\epsilon} \right)$$
are characteristics for the velocity field 
$$
B_\epsilon(t,x,y)=\left(b(t,x), \frac{b(t,x+\epsilon y) - b(t,x)}{\epsilon} \right)
$$
and as $\epsilon \to 0$ we have $\Phi_\epsilon(t,x,y) \to \Phi(t,x,y)$ locally in measure, where $\Phi$ is the characteristic for $B(t,x,y) = (b(t,x), \nabla_x b(t,x)y)$.

Why does this not work if $b$ is $BV$ instead of $W^{1,1}$?

Comment: What is the limit of $B_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ if $b$ is $BV$?

Comment: @Romeo That's part of the problem. I'd be satisfied to know that $\{\Phi_\epsilon\}$ has some compactness and converge locally in measure to some $\Phi$.